# Installing PCIe SATA card conflicts with onboard NIC

Tags: networking, server, sata, pcie

I recently installed a fresh 21.04 server onto new hardware. Everything worked great. Today, I tried to add an ASM1166 based PCIe SATA controller. When I boot with the card in, it causes issues with my onboard NIC (RTL8125). The issue appears to happen during the boot process as the NIC lights turn on and flash when the computer starts, then suddenly go out halfway through startup. If I shutdown, remove the card, then restart, everything works great again.

The first thing I noticed is the interface changed name from enp4s0 to enp5s0. Running `lshw -c network` shows the interface exists with the correct hardware, but shows `*-network disabled`. Running `ip link set enp5s0 up` causes the NIC lights to turn on, but I can't connect through the interface. Running `lspci -v`shows both SATA controller and NIC to be connected.

I'm at a loss of how to proceed. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. The issue was the logical name changing from enp4s0 to enp5s0. I followed the instructions here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration and set my NIC to a static logical name of enp4s0 by matching the MAC address. This allowed the system to use the already determined settings created during install and connect to the network.